# Modify working makefile to do pre-stage before compiling and linking

Tags: makefile, compiler-errors, gnu-make

I'm using this makefile as an example:

https://gist.github.com/mihaitodor/bfb8e7ad908489fdf3ceb496573f306a

Before compiling/linking I need to do a pre-stage, consisting of `cd` to a directory and run a script. Without the pre-stage it compiles & links fine.

I think I need to change the `all` rule:

```
all : $(TESTS)
```

I have tried this:

```
all : cd /bla/bla ./my_script $(TESTS)
```

and I have tried this:

```
all :
     cd /bla/bla ./my_script
     $(TESTS)
```

but it stops the compile/linking stage.

Given the URL above, where should I insert my pre-stage?

Comment: I mean just to point out, but `cd /bla/blah ./my_script` is not a valid shell command.  Maybe you mean `cd /bla/bla && ./my_script` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is you should likely create a new recipe, and make any bottom level target that is dependent on your script running be dependent on it.   Something like:

```
.ran_my_script: $(GTEST_SRCS_)
   cd /bla/bla ./my_script
   touch $@

test_mihai.o gtest_main.o gtest.o : .ran_my_script
```

This way it will run your script *before* it attempts to generate any of the listed targets.   It then touches a file `$@` (`.ran_my_script`).   This will then be newer than any of the .o files meaning the script will not rerun unless someone modifies one of the scripts dependencies (i.e.  `$(GTEST_SRCS_)`).   You'll have to figure out what artifcats are actually dependent on your script, and what artifacts your script is dependent on.

Notice that if any of the sources change, then `.ran_my_script` will be considered out of date, as will anything that depends on it.   This means that if you modify any source, it will rebuild all .o files.   I'm assuming this is what you want.

Because I'm assuming you're new to makefiles, I will point out two things: first `$@` resolves to the target name (`.ran_my_script` in the above example), and second, that the last line of this causes `.ran_my_script` to be a dependency of `test_mihai.o` and friends -- but because it does not have any recipes associated with it, this line does not override any other recipes against the same targets specified prior to or later on in the makefile.

---

As to why what you were doing doesn't work:

```
all: cd /bla/blah ./my_script $(TESTS)
```

indicates that the target `all` is dependent on the targets `cd`, `/bla/bla`, `./my_script`, and `$(TESTS)`.   It will attempt to build all of these before it builds `all`.   Of course, you likely do not have a rule to build `cd`, etc, so this will fail.

Your next example,

```
all :
     cd /bla/bla ./my_script
     $(TESTS)
```

You create a target all, with two recipes.   First, it will attempt to run your script, and then it will attempt to run whatever `$(TESTS)` resolves to.   Notice that `$(TESTS)` in this case is not a bash command, so this would fail as well.

You might be tempted to do something like this:

```
all : $(TESTS)
     cd /bla/bla ./my_script
```

but this would cause your script to be run as part of the `all` target, which runs *after* everything in `$(TESTS)` has already been completed.